# Elasticsearch throwing exception circuit_breaking_exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch throwing below exception

```
\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"circuit_breaking_exception\",\"reason\":\"[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [16351863432/15.2gb], which is larger than the limit of [16254631936/15.1gb], real usage: [16351862128/15.2gb], new bytes reserved: [1304/1.2kb]\",\"bytes_wanted\":16351863432,\"bytes_limit\":16254631936}],\"type\":\"circuit_breaking_exception\",\"reason\":\"[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [16351863432/15.2gb], which is larger than the limit of [16254631936/15.1gb], real usage: [16351862128/15.2gb], new bytes reserved: [1304/1.2kb]\",\"bytes_wanted\":16351863432,\"bytes_limit\":16254631936},\"status\":429}"}
```

I increased indices.breaker.request.limit to 50%. but still getting same error

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "indices.breaker.request.limit" : "50" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of increasing the limit for your parent circuit breaker, default of which is 70%, you have decreased it to 50%, please increase it to higher value and check.**

Refer [parent-circuit beaker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html#parent-circuit-breaker) doc for more info, and from same doc

> indices.breaker.total.limit logo cloud (Dynamic) Starting limit for
> overall parent breaker. **Defaults to 70% of JVM heap if**
> indices.breaker.total.use_real_memory is false.

If

> indices.breaker.total.use_real_memory is true, defaults to 95% of the
> JVM heap.

Comment: I increased indices.breaker.request.limit to 80% but still getting the same exception  circuit_breaking_exception. any another solution.

Comment: @NareshSingh how much heap of ES and RAM of machine you have?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late response.
 we are using 2 nodes with 16 GB ram each. 
by default heap takes half of total RAM i.e.  it takes total heap of 16 GB

Comment: @NareshSingh, you mean 8 GB of heap on each node? and how many docs your are searching, looks like you have to increase the RAM and heap of ES..

Comment: thousands of docs. actually we are moving dynamic mapping to static mapping in elasticsearch. we also set dynamic false while we are mapping. I checked my logs and found out that I have exceed the limit of fields which is 70000. I am new to elasticsearch. I am not sure because of field limit exception. I am getting a circuit breaker exception.

Comment: so elasticsearch throwing exception:
1. circuit breaker exception
2. \"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"remote_transport_exception\",\"reason\":\"[E5tCUYZ][x.x.x.x:9300][indices:admin/create]\"}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Limit of total fields [70000] in index [rides_order_651] has been exceeded\"}

Comment: @NareshSingh looks like you are mixing the two exception, are these coming at the same time? you can increase the total limit on fields by following the link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings and relavent setting is called as `index.mapping.total_fields.limit`

Comment: @NareshSingh, could you please do the needful, as mentioned in my last comment